# how to get some child list from Firebase android kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

How i can read just color item in the image with out all data sub child?

I try this

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val personalDataReference = database.getReference("user personal data")
val messageList = ArrayList<String>()
personalDataReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot){
        messageList.add(dataSnapshot.value.toString())
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
    }
})
```

but it get all the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things you've marked yellow are known as *keys* in Firebase terms.

To get a list of only the keys, you can do:

```
personalDataReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot){
      for (childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
        messageList.add(childSnapshot.key)
      }
    }
```

Note that this will still read all JSON from the database, but the list will only contain the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [Firebase Kotlin SDK](https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk) by GitLive.

This library is also multi-platform, so the same code can be used on both Android *and* on iOS via [Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile](https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/).

The code to read the keys from Firebase realtime database would look like this:

```
val keys = db.reference("/path/to/user personal data")
  .valueEvents
  .first()
  .children
  .mapNotNull { it.key }
```

Note here that `valueEvents` is a Kotlin [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html) of `DataSnapshot`, therefore you can do more than simply taking the first snapshot and mapping it to a list as shown above. See the `Flow` documentation.